# Java JTextPane or JTextArea set characters per line before wrapping

Tags: java, character, limit, jtextarea, jtextpane

I have a 64-character "key" (text) that I want to display in a limited amount of space (width) using a swing JPanel containing a JTextPanel or JTextArea. All the text is alphanumeric, with no spaces, and I am using a monospace font to display it. I'd like to print the key in 4 lines of 16 characters. My code:

```
JTextArea key = new JTextArea();
key.setColumns(16);
key.setRows(4);
key.setLineWrap(true);
key.setWrapStyleWord(true);
key.setText("475EC49A50F35BA50FE5791B8ECFC12515393A5A200C6BA2C82B290C053A6C85");
JPanel keypanel = new JPanel();
keypanel.add(privatekeybackuptext);
```

When I run it, it prints more than 16 characters per line. It just prints as many as it can fit in the arbitrarily-sized box and the textarea/textpane ends up with 2.5 lines of hex characters. I am guessing that either setColumns and setRows has nothing to do with how text is displayed or the layout manager is overriding something? So far, I have tried setting the layoutmanager of the panel to the default FlowLayout and I have also tried GridBagConstraints with fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH. Neither worked. I know I could fake it by counting off 16 characters and adding a newline, but I'd rather do it correctly. What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: That’s going to be difficult, since you have no guarantee regarding the font a JTextArea will use, therefore you have no guarantee of how many characters will fit on a line.  Why not break up the string into four lines of length 16?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am guessing that either setColumns and setRows has nothing to do with how text is displayed

Set columns will size the text area so that it can contain 16 "W" characters.

> When I run it, it prints more than 16 characters per line

You will need to use a monospaced font.

```
textArea.setFont(new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 12));
```

Now an "I" is the same as a "W" so you should have 16 characters on each row.

Comment: This solved the problem, using exactly your line of text. Ironically, I had tried adding a monospace font (Inconsolata) by registering the ttf file and setting the font to that (and I know it worked because it showed the font), but for whatever reason, that font did not do what your line did, which was give me exactly what I wanted.